# Can Blackberry Java do parameterized types?

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm using Blackberry JDE 5.0.0, I can use `Vector` to store a growable list of objects, but I'm wondering if there's an ArrayList<T> type class that supports parameterized types on BB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BlackBerry conforms to the J2ME spec which is a subset of the J2SE spec in terms of available APIs.  For example the Collections API is not available.  Also, the language level used is Java 1.3 so things such as generics and autoboxing are not supported.

Comment: For every fact I learn about Java ME, I am that much more thankful that I don't have to use it.

Comment: Haha!  Exactly.  It's a pain but you get used to it.

Comment: There is no [`enum`](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?106986-enum-keyword)

Comment: No phones, no lights, no motor car, not a single luxury. Like Robinson Crusoe, it's primitive as can be.